# Artifactory is bypassing its local cache and downloading list.manifest.json from docker-remote even though it is present in artifactory cache

Tags: docker, artifactory

We are not able to find out why Artifactory started making calls to docker remote for pulling the list.manifest.json even though it exists in its local cache. It used to work fine earlier but suddenly we started seeing sharp jump in the number of requests being made to docker remote. Please note that this behaviour is observed only for list.manifest.json and manifest.json. Blobs are correctly being served from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The list.manifest.json and manifest.json are metadata files and are considered an expirable resource.
When a tag is overwritten on the upstream, those files are updated (usually occurs with the 'latest' tag).

Once the Metadata [Cache Retrieval Period](https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-remote-repository-metadata-works/metadata-cache-retrieval-period) is passed, Artifactory will check if a newer version of the manifest was deployed and will download if there is one.

If a tag was updated on the upstream and the Metadata Cache Retrieval Period was not passed, Artifactory will serve the image from the cache.

Comment: It is not being served from the cache even when metadata cache retrieval period has not  passed. This behaviour is intermittent. Around 50% manifest requests are served from cache and for 50% it is calling docker remote even when the image exists in cache.